# OpenDaylight: Listen for flow updates

Tags: opendaylight

I am trying to implement an OpenDaylight bundle that receives notifications when flows change. Therefore, I implemented `DataTreeChangeListener<Flow>`. The project compiles and starts (`./karaf/target/assembly/bin/karaf`), but when I install additional package (`feature:install odl-restconf odl-l2switch-switch odl-dluxapps-yangvisualizer odl-dluxapps-yangman odl-dlux-core odl-dluxapps-nodes odl-dluxapps-topology odl-mdsal-apidocs`), I get the following error:

```
Unsatisfied Requirements:
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.netconf.sal.rest.api)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.netconf.sal.restconf.api)"
Unsatisfied Requirements:
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.codecs)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.handlers)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.jersey.providers)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.jersey.providers.api)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.jersey.providers.patch)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.jersey.providers.schema)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.jersey.providers.spi)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.references)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.rests.services.api)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.rests.transactions)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.services.simple.api)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.streams.listeners)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.streams.websockets)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.utils)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.utils.mapping)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.utils.parser)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.utils.parser.builder)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.utils.validations)"
Error executing command: Error restarting bundles:
    Could not resolve module: org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-bierman02 [318]
  Bundle was not resolved because of a uses contraint violation.
  org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-bierman02 [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-bierman02"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.0.SNAPSHOT"] because it is exposed to package 'javax.annotation' from resources javax.annotation-api [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="javax.annotation-api"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.2.0"] and org.eclipse.osgi [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.osgi"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.11.3.v20170209-1843"; singleton:="true"] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-bierman02 [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-bierman02"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.0.SNAPSHOT"]
    import: (osgi.wiring.package=javax.annotation)
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: javax.annotation
  javax.annotation-api [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="javax.annotation-api"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.2.0"]

Chain 2:
  org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-bierman02 [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-bierman02"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.0.SNAPSHOT"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(&(version>=23.3.0)(!(version>=24.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base; uses:=javax.annotation
  com.google.guava [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="com.google.guava"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="23.3.0.jre"]
    import: (osgi.wiring.package=javax.annotation)
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: javax.annotation
  org.eclipse.osgi [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.osgi"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.11.3.v20170209-1843"; singleton:="true"]
    Could not resolve module: org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-rfc8040 [319]
  Bundle was not resolved because of a uses contraint violation.
  org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-rfc8040 [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-rfc8040"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.0.SNAPSHOT"] because it is exposed to package 'javax.annotation' from resources javax.annotation-api [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="javax.annotation-api"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.2.0"] and org.eclipse.osgi [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.osgi"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.11.3.v20170209-1843"; singleton:="true"] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-rfc8040 [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-rfc8040"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.0.SNAPSHOT"]
    import: (osgi.wiring.package=javax.annotation)
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: javax.annotation
  javax.annotation-api [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="javax.annotation-api"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.2.0"]

Chain 2:
  org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-rfc8040 [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.opendaylight.netconf.restconf-nb-rfc8040"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.0.SNAPSHOT"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(&(version>=23.3.0)(!(version>=24.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base; uses:=javax.annotation
  com.google.guava [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="com.google.guava"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="23.3.0.jre"]
    import: (osgi.wiring.package=javax.annotation)
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: javax.annotation
  org.eclipse.osgi [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.osgi"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.11.3.v20170209-1843"; singleton:="true"]
karaf@root()> Unsatisfied Requirements:                                                                                                                                                                                                    
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.netconf.sal.rest.api)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.netconf.sal.restconf.api)"
Unsatisfied Requirements:
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.codecs)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.handlers)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.jersey.providers)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.jersey.providers.api)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.jersey.providers.patch)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.jersey.providers.schema)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.jersey.providers.spi)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.references)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.rests.services.api)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.rests.transactions)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.services.simple.api)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.streams.listeners)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.streams.websockets)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.utils)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.utils.mapping)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.utils.parser)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.utils.parser.builder)"
osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.opendaylight.restconf.nb.rfc8040.utils.validations)"
```

What am I missing? The complete code is available at [Github](https://github.com/ne0h/flowlistener)

Thanks in advance!
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeing this on the latest ODL (Oxygen), then this is the same problem that recently sometimes surfaced on OpenDaylight's integration build as well... we are now tracking this in https://jira.opendaylight.org/browse/NETCONF-516.

We are hoping that merge of https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/#/c/68255/ will fix this in the short term, also https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/#/c/67184/ should help in the longer term (when projects bump to new odlparent); you could also try https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/#/c/68199/ although that was found not to help.

Comment: Thanks for this information! I tried to downgrade to restconf-1.5.4, but I got different errors like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024264/opendaylight-error-installing-boot-features

Comment: Max at this point you should perhaps set up an account on https://identity.linuxfoundation.org so that you can start watching and get notified of JIRAs, such as NETCONF-516, that way you would get notifications about its progress, and see that a fix for it has meanwhile been found and is about to be merged into master...

Comment: Yes, that is why i tried to downgrade netconf in the meantime. I am going to set up an account to get notified.