# OpenDaylight: Error installing boot features

Tags: karaf, opendaylight

I am facing this error:

```
2018-02-28T08:30:08,419 | ERROR | pool-1-thread-2  | BootFeaturesInstaller            | 7 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.1.3 | Error installing boot features
org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=b9b64fb5-51e0-4ead-92af-087b5f324d3e; type=karaf.feature; version="[0,0.0.0]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=b9b64fb5-51e0-4ead-92af-087b5f324d3e)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=0.0.0)(version<=0.0.0))" [caused by: Unable to resolve b9b64fb5-51e0-4ead-92af-087b5f324d3e/0.0.0: missing requirement [b9b64fb5-51e0-4ead-92af-087b5f324d3e/0.0.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-flowlistener-rest; type=karaf.feature [caused by: Unable to resolve odl-flowlistener-rest/0.1.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [odl-flowlistener-rest/0.1.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-restconf; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.7.0.SNAPSHOT,1.7.0.SNAPSHOT]" [caused by: Unable to resolve odl-restconf/1.7.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [odl-restconf/1.7.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-restconf-noauth; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.7.0.SNAPSHOT,1.7.0.SNAPSHOT]" [caused by: Unable to resolve odl-restconf-noauth/1.7.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [odl-restconf-noauth/1.7.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-aaa-shiro; type=karaf.feature; version="[0.7.0.SNAPSHOT,0.7.0.SNAPSHOT]" [caused by: Unable to resolve odl-aaa-shiro/0.7.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [odl-aaa-shiro/0.7.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-aaa-cert; type=karaf.feature; version="[0.7.0.SNAPSHOT,0.7.0.SNAPSHOT]" [caused by: Unable to resolve odl-aaa-cert/0.7.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [odl-aaa-cert/0.7.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-mdsal-broker; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.7.0.SNAPSHOT,1.7.0.SNAPSHOT]" [caused by: Unable to resolve odl-mdsal-broker/1.7.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [odl-mdsal-broker/1.7.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-mdsal-remoterpc-connector; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.7.0.SNAPSHOT,1.7.0.SNAPSHOT]" [caused by: Unable to resolve odl-mdsal-remoterpc-connector/1.7.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [odl-mdsal-remoterpc-connector/1.7.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-mdsal-broker-local; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.7.0.SNAPSHOT,1.7.0.SNAPSHOT]" [caused by: Unable to resolve odl-mdsal-broker-local/1.7.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [odl-mdsal-broker-local/1.7.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-config-netty; type=karaf.feature; version="[0.8.0.SNAPSHOT,0.8.0.SNAPSHOT]" [caused by: Unable to resolve odl-config-netty/0.8.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [odl-config-netty/0.8.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-config-startup; type=karaf.feature; version="[0.8.0.SNAPSHOT,0.8.0.SNAPSHOT]" [caused by: Unable to resolve odl-config-startup/0.8.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [odl-config-startup/0.8.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-config-persister; type=karaf.feature; version="[0.8.0.SNAPSHOT,0.8.0.SNAPSHOT]" [caused by: Unable to resolve odl-config-persister/0.8.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [odl-config-persister/0.8.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.opendaylight.controller.config-persister-file-xml-adapter; type=osgi.fragment; version="[0.8.0.SNAPSHOT,0.8.0.SNAPSHOT]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Fragment was not selected for attachment: org.opendaylight.controller.config-persister-file-xml-adapter/0.8.0.SNAPSHOT]]]]]]]]]]]]]
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolutionError.toException(ResolutionError.java:42) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.doResolve(ResolverImpl.java:391) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:377) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:349) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:218) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:291) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1248) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$1(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1147) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:?]
```

Looks like I am missing a boot dependency? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [OpenDaylight: Listen for flow updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48976008/opendaylight-listen-for-flow-updates/48988616?noredirect=1#comment85053246_48988616) this happened to you when you downgraded restconf.. I would not do that.